# How to import a Cocoapods subspec/ module instead of the entire pod in Swift

Tags: cocoapods

A subspec *"represents specification for a module of the library."*.

Here's an example of a `.Podspec` file taken from [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec):

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'RestKit'

  s.subspec 'Core' do |cs|
    cs.dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping'
    cs.dependency 'RestKit/Network'
    cs.dependency 'RestKit/CoreData'
  end

  s.subspec 'ObjectMapping' do |os|
  end
end
```

Inside Swift, how would someone import the **only** the `ObjectMapping` **subspec**, instead of the whole Cocoapos Pod? The documentation does say its a "module of the library" so this leads me to believe there is some way to import the module/ subspec individually. Unfortunately for me, *maybe* their definition of module is different to a [Swift module](https://swift.org/package-manager/#modules) and this feature doesn't exist. I am aware of only this import for the whole pod:

```swift
import RestKit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not possible

This is not possible, because `Podspec`s define the clang module generated.

I inferred this from the `module_name` documentation:

> The name to use for the framework / clang module which will be generated for this specification instead of the default (header_dir if set, otherwise the specification name).

...where specification means `Podspec`.

### Workaround

Create multiple Podspec files (clang modules). You can put them in the same directory. For example, [**Github:** mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios) has 2 podspecs in the root directory, which refer to other Podspecs elsewhere.